# Java error handling for null pointer exception in array

Tags: java, arraylist, error-handling

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I did some searching and couldn't find my specific scenario.

I was wondering if I could get some advise on the best way to deal with null exception errors with functions that try and return an object from an ArrayList by an ID if the parsed ID isn't found in the index of the ArrayList.

I have a Project class that has an ArrayList of Task objects:

```
private ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
```

and I have a getting function in the Project class to try and return a Task by it's ID from the ArrayList:

```
public Task getTask(int id)  {
    if(id > 0 && id <= tasks.size()) {
        for(Task task : tasks) {
            if(task.getID() == id) {
                return task;
            }
        }
    } else { 
        Globals.log("Couldt find Task with ID of: " + id + " in Project: " + title); 
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I try and call a function in a Task by getting a Task from ID, if the Tasks ID doesn't exist in the index of the ArrayList, naturally I get a null exception error, eg if there is no Task with an ID of 15, this code will fail with a null exception pointer:

```
project.getTask(15).addTag("Test");
```

My question is, can I do some error handling in the `getTask(int id)` function to log the error before the program crashes?

I've tried adding a `try {} catch {}` block around it, but it still doesn't run my `Globals.log()` function before it crashes.

Adding a 
`try {} catch {}` block works if I do the error handling in the `addTag();` function in the Task class, but I would rather not have to go through all my functions in the Task class and add `try {} catch {}` to every function.

Is there a better solution to this problem?

Comment: Why crash at all? Task task = project.getTag(15). if (task!=null){task.addTag("Test");} else {do your reporting}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From java 8 you can use `Optional` as return type if `Task` is present in array return `Optional` with `Task` else empty `Optional`

```
public Optional<Task> getTask(int id)  {
if(id > 0 && id <= tasks.size()) {
    for(Task task : tasks) {
        if(task.getID() == id) {
            return Optional.of(task);
        }
    }
} 

 Globals.log("Couldt find Task with ID of: " + id + " in Project: " + title); 

return Optional.empty();
}
```

And from [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) you can use `ifPresent` by avoiding `try-catch` and `null` check also

```
project.getTask(15).ifPresent(t->t.addTag("test"));
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was after! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think [Deadpool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087658/java-error-handling-for-null-exception-pointer-in-array/60087696#60087696) solved the NPE issue, but there is another slight oversight in your code.

If in the case of the IDs not being sequentially ordered then your first check `if(id > 0 && id <= tasks.size())` will cause issues and removing it would be a good idea:

```
public Optional<Task> getTask(int id) {
    for (Task task : tasks) {
        if (task.getID() == id) {
            return Optional.of(task);
        }
    }

    Globals.log("Couldt find Task with ID of: " + id + " in Project: " + title);

    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: Yeah your right, that check is redundant with the ```Optional``` implementation. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use try/catch in this case.

You need to check if getTask method return NULL value before using it like this:

```
public void test() {
   Task task = project.getTask(15);
   if (task != null) {
      task.addTag("Test");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Task taskObj=null;

        for(Task task : tasks) {
            if(task.getID() == id) {
                taskObj= task;
            }
        }
    if(taskObj!=null)
    { 
        return null;
    }else{
        Globals.log("Couldt find Task with ID of: " + id + " in Project: " + title); 
        return null;
    }
}

public void mainClass() {
   Task task = project.getTask(15);
   if (task != null) {
      task.addTag("Test");
   }
}
```